# How to read tomcat error log

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

Here is a screenshot of my tomcat spring boot error log. How do I read this?[image]

Specifically,

1.) where do I read there is says "63 more"?

2.) Is the top-most error the most generic, or most specific? I'm thinking most generic because it says "caused by" and then another error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, get destination of log (console, file, database, ...) by find information in:

   - application.properties (for example: spring.log.**** = ...)
   - or `log4j.properties/log4j.yml/log4j.yaml` (if using log4j)
   - or `log4j2.properties/log4j2.yml/log4j2.yaml` (if using log4j2)
   - or `logback.properties/logback.yml` (if using logback)
     and then you can get "63 more" there
2. It's the most specific
   most specific error <== root cause is here
   ^ cause by: generic error
   ^ cause by: generic error
   ...
   ^ cause by: most generic error

Answer (score 0):

The first line contains the exact reason for the error, such as this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
abc.def.ghi.handleRequest(MyController.java:30)
...
```

The more you go down, the more information you get about the root cause. Usually you can find the cause at the bottom of the log message containing the stack trace. In your case, the cause for the exception is "No converter found capable of converting from type ...".